# Custom post type as subpage to Page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created a custom post type named 'bikes'. I have also a page named 'bikes for sale'. On my bikes-PAGE I list all bikes-posttypes. But how can I make them behave like subpages to my bikes-PAGE? For example I want to be able to click on a bike that has been listed, and then be redirected to a page with more info about that bike.

Im use to Umbraco where this is superdupereasy. You just create a page and then make a doctype that you can create under that page..

Right now Ive created a custom template and selected it on my bikes-page, this template uses a query to get all bike-posttypes and then lists them on the page.

Answer (score 0):

**To Create child page**,

Simply **"Create"** or **"edit"** a Page in WordPress.

Under the **"Page Attributes Section"** -> Choose a **"Parent"** page from the **drop down list**.

Your work is done.

Now, You displaying Child Pages List on the Parent Page in WordPress, you need to add the following code in your **functions.php** file:

```
function wp_list_child_pages() { 
    global $post; 

    if ( is_page() && $post->post_parent )
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->post_parent . '&echo=0' );
    else
        $childpages = wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&title_li=&child_of=' . $post->ID . '&echo=0' );

    if ( $childpages ) {  
        $string = '<ul>' . $childpages . '</ul>';
    }  
    return $string;
}

add_shortcode('wp_childpages', 'wp_list_child_pages');
```

To display all child pages put following line in **page/text widget** in the **sidebar**:

```
[wp_childpages]
```

Hope this help.

Comment: tnx but thats not what im looking for. Indeed this will make subpages, but they wont be related to my custom post types. And it wouldnt make much sense to add a subpage like that for my bikes